# Shipping projects as NuGet packages while depending on each other

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I have three projects I'm building

- FooBar.Abstractions
- FooBar.AspNetCore
- FooBar.AspNetCore.IntegrationTesting

The `FooBar.AspNetCore` and the `FooBar.AspNetCore.IntegrationTesting` projects both have references to `FooBar.Abstractions`. I want to package and ship all three of these as individual NuGet packages.

I started with a `NuGet.config` file that looks like this locally:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
      <add key="aspnetcore_abstractions" value="./src/FooBar.Abstractions/bin/Debug/" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Then I add the package to my projects

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FooBar.Abstractions" Version="2.0.0-preview1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This really sucks though as each time I make a change in the `FooBar.Abstractions` project I have to go into my C:\.nuget\packages folder and delete the cache before my `FooBar.AspNetCore` project can restore the newly compiled version from my solution.

If I just add `FooBar.Abstractions` as a project reference, and then I ship the two packages to NuGet.org, how does that affect users that install the two packages across different projects in their solutions. Does NuGet and .Net figure it all out, knowing that they're the same referenced assembly? I assume in this case the `FooBar.AspNetCore` project will ship with the `FooBar.Abstractions.dll` in it if I add it as a project reference.

I don't know if that causes conflicts knowing that the package ships that .dll, then a customer installs the Abstractions package explicitly that contains the same .dll.

How do you handle this with NuGet packaging with the newest versions of NuGet? How do I constrain `FooBar.AspNetCore` to use the same `FooBar.Abstractions.dll` version between the package reference and the NuGet package others will install? I can't force `PackageReference Include="FooBar.Abstractions" Version="2.2"` if I'm adding it as a project reference instead can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pack a project with at project reference, NuGet converts the project reference into a NuGet dependency. It figures out the dependency version based on what version that project would be if it were packed. There is no need to use `PackageReference` when packing. As you discovered/explained, doing so makes local development much more difficult.

Therefore the solution to your problem is to just use `ProjectReference` when the projects are in the same source code repository.